# What does *& mean when used in argument?

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, reference, arguments

I was wondering was *& means. 
Context:

A function is implemented as follows:

```
void headInsert( Node*& head, int info )
{
    Node* temp = new Node(info);
    temp->link = head;
    head = temp;
}
```

WHy not just use Node& ?

Thanks

Comment: You should tag the question with the language you are using.

Answer (score 3):

`Node*&` means "a reference to a pointer to Node" while `Node&` means "a reference to Node".

> Why not just use Node& ?

Because the `headInsert` function needs to change what the head is pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the specific call, where reference pointers reveal their use:

```
Node* pHead = somewhere;
headInsert(pHead, info);
// pHead does now point to the newly allocated node, generated inside headInser, 
// by new Node(info), but NOT to 'somewhere'
```

Let me comment on your example, maybe that makes it more clear:

```
void headInsert( Node*& head, int info )
{
    Node* temp = new Node(info); // generate a new head, the future head
    temp->link = head; // let the former head be a member/child of the new head
    head = temp; // 'overwrite' the former head pointer outside of the call by the new head
}
```